# Завершение потоков при многопоточной обработке файла

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, mutex

Есть Json файл большого размера(1,5гб+). Для его обработки использую QJson в нескольких потоках

Есть:

```
void handleJsonAcync(std::queue<QString>&,bool& status);//вызов потоков
void handleJson(std::queue<QString>&,bool&,int id);//обработчик строк
std::vector<std::thread> threadPool;
std::mutex mutex;
```

Вызовов потоков происходит максимально просто:

```
//status передается из цикла чтения файла и меняется когда файл прочитан и Que пуста (обработаны все строки)    
void handleJsonAcync(std::queue<QString>&Que,bool &stats)
    {
        threadPool.push_back(std::thread(handleJson,std::ref(Que),std::ref(stats),1));
        threadPool.back().detach();
        threadPool.push_back(std::thread(handleJson,std::ref(Que),std::ref(stats),2));
        threadPool.back().detach();
    }
```

Обработчик строк содержит мьютекс чтобы потоки по одному брали строку из очереди

```
void handleJson(std::queue<QString>&Que,bool &stats, int id)
{
    QJsonArray obj;
    while(true)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        //пытаемся взять строку из очереди   
        tryPutJson:
        if(!stats) break;
        else if(!Que.empty())
        {
            obj = QJsonDocument::fromJson(Que.front().toUtf8()).array();
            Que.pop();
        }
        else goto tryPutJson;

        mutex.unlock();
        //если взяли строку то обрабатываем
        if(!obj.isEmpty())
        {
            countsys++;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Thread: "<<id<< " out!";
}
```

По завершению ожидается что оба потока напишут "Thread out", но пишет только один, либо 1 либо 2, отсюда возникают сомнения в корректной работе, хотелось бы узнать почему только один поток выходит из цикла и какие мьютексы правильнее здесь использовать? Так как думаю дело в них

Comment: В приведенных кусках кода явная ошибка проглядывается только одна - вызов `detach`. Ну и ручное управление мьютексом, да еще и с goto. Надо было приводить [mcve].

Comment: выход из цикла по `if(!stats) break;` оставляет `mutex` залоченным. Используйте [lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

Comment: из за цикла на `goto` поток зависает на пустой очереди

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос информацию: К моменту запуска потоков очередь заполнена или наполняется во время их работы? За что отвечает параметр `stats` и меняется ли его значение во время работы потоков?

Comment: while(true), goto внутри этого while которое ведет наверх, использование mutex.lock вместо lock_guard, условие выхода привязано на переменную извне... да тут полный набор, удивительно что вообще что-то работает! Вот у вас есть очередь из которой потоки берут на обработку данные - для этого вам приходится использовать мьютекс, но почему бы не разбить очередь перед тем как отдавать данные потоком? В этом случае вы избавитесь от блокирований а условие выхода будет упрощено до `que.empty()`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Очередь заполняется по мере чтения большого файла, который нельзя прочитать полностью сразу, и хранить весь файл в очереди довольно дорого, lock_guard полностью решил всю мою проблему, можно избавиться от while(true) и заменить его на рекурсию, но и так получается что один поток считывает данные и два их обрабатывают по очереди

Comment: @MaximTimakov Очередь наполняется во время работы потоков, параметр stats выполняет роль флага, он изменяется когда поток считывания считал все строки и очередь опустошилась(то есть все строки обработаны) и тогда он сообщает потокам что пора выходить из цикла

Comment: Пробовал вместо detach() писать join() но тогда это не работает, так как основной поток ждет пока поток с join() закончит свою работу и не считывает данные, а поток не может закончить работу так как данных не поступало, можно конечно сделать отдельный поток для считывания(не основной) но нужно ли?
Пока что я придумал только такую концепцию, но если есть что то более красивое и производительное то всегда готов исправить

Comment: @AntKerf так а в чем тогда толк в этой многопоточности, когда ваши потоки все равно работают по очереди? Это тоже самое, если бы у вас был один поток, который бы обрабатывал очередь. При этом это было бы и проще и даже быстрее. Выгода от использования потоков наступает тогда, когда они работают независимо.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Выгода в том что обработка данных которая там происходит довольна затратна из за работы с бд, толк от многопоточности в том что  данные обрабатываются одновременно в двух потоках, соотвественно производительность в 2 раза выше это я замерял через QDataTime. По очереди они только берут эти данные а обрабатывают независимо друг от друга после mutex.unlock() поток с данными начинает их обрабатывать а другой поток берет данные и затем тоже их обратывает

Answer (score 0):

выход из цикла по `if(!stats) break;` оставляет `mutex` залоченным. Используйте [lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)